# regex to find number preceded and followed by different strings

Tags: regex, bash, match

I have a text file containing text and numbers, for example:

```
MANGO444CHERRYa.b /c-1@2#3APPLEa>b;c. a1$2$3WHITE12 3ab cWHITE5%6^7a=b +cWHITEaba5b6a7baMANGO555CHERRY 1'2'3a,b,c!APPPLE1`2~3ab @cYELLOW123---a- -bcYELLOW
```

I need to get he number between `MANGO` and `CHERRY` that comes before `APPLE` and `WHITE`  (in this case, `444`).  The text between the uppercase words can be anything at all.  I tried this:

```
(?<=MANGO)\d+((=?.*?APPLE)(=?.*?WHITE))
```

but it returns:

```
444CHERRYa.b /c-1@2#3APPLEB>b;c. a1$2$3WHITE
```

I hope this demonstrates the problem in a better way

Comment: In your example no ID is followed by BLACK. Please edit your question providing a better explanation and an output sample.

Comment: And maybe start with the trivial solution `MANGO([0-9]+)BLACK.*` and explain why that isn't working.

Comment: the solution above wouldn't work because the are numbers between MANGO and BLACK other than <ID>, and <ID> IS followed by BLACK, only after some text. for example: 123abcMANGO<ID>123abcAPPLE123abcBLACK

Comment: In your example, change "some text alphanumeric, digits and non-alphanumeric characters" to (eg) "text, digits and non-alphanumerics", or perhaps to different representative strings in each line, to decrease the uninformative parts of your question; and instead of <ID> show different numbers.  Also, if MANGO, APPLE and BLACK can appear in the same line, fix the example in the question to show it.  Also, if you use anchors in regexs for grep, use -P switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. I'm using sed though.

```
sed -nr 's/.*MANGO([0-9]+).*APPLE.*WHITE.*/\1/p' yourfile
```

Edited to check for APPLE in between MANGO and WHITE.

Limitation: works only when MANGO-APPLE-WHITE occurs only once within the line.

Without the `-n` option and `p` flag, `sed` would simply print out the line when no match is found.

Comment: excellent!!, but what about APPLE? i guess i didn't explain the problem right (again) :( (sorry about that) i need to match APPLE and WHITE, or APPLE and YELLOW, depending on sed configuration. this because later on in the text APPLE will become ORANGE and i don't want the numbers followed by ORANGE

Comment: edited again... I think this works now for your case, assuming that the MANGO...APPLE...WHITE combination only occurs once within the line.

Comment: right, almost there :) this works for MANGO444CHERRY--ORANGE--WHITE--WHITE--MANGO555CHERRY--ORANGE--BLACK--BLACK > if i search for MANGO..ORANGE..WHITE i get 444 (good!) and if for MANGO..ORANGE..BLACK i get 555 (good!) but in case i have MANGO..APPLE..WHITE i get the whole line (not good, in this case i need the command to return nothing)

Comment: just to clarify the above - [MANGO..APPLE..WHITE] means NOT MANGO..ORANGE..SOMETHING

Comment: ok I see the problem. Adding `-n` option and `p` flag should fix this.

Comment: doubleDown - apparntly the command works on sample text, nut not on the actual text i want to parse, so i'm gonna ask a new question with the actual data, please take a look if you will. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to catch groups of decimals between `MANGO` and `BLACK` or `APPLE`:

```
etuardu@subranu:~$ echo '
> MANGO0012BLACK
> MANGO0045txt
> MANGO2314APPLE
> txt00313BLACK' | grep -Po '(?<=MANGO)\d+(?=BLACK|APPLE)'
0012
2314
```

Comment: thank you for your help!, i need BLACK and APPLE. please see edited queation